# Use "grep" to match text in multiple files

Tags: linux, grep

I have data in multiple files. I want to find some text that matches in all files. Can I use the `grep` command for that? If yes then how?

Comment: This is bizarrely obvious, in that "grep PATTERN file1 file2 ..." will work.  Do you mean to do something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not know where exactly the files are located, but know their names, you can use `find`:

```
find .  \( -name "filename1" -o -name "filename2" \) -exec grep "<grepstatement>" '{}' \; -print
```

Assuming that the files are in this directory somewhere.

Comment: 1. You use "and" instead of "or" logic between the files, 2. There is no need for mixing `find` into this, 3. Just what would be the purpose of the `-print` at the end?!

Comment: Good point with the and/or. I just fixed it. You also have a point about not needing to use find, I use the command when I don't know what which file things are in but know what information I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, so I edited so that it looks more justified. But note that using `-print` at the end is not too good (my 3rd point in the previous comment) - it messes up the output; if you want to learn the location of the files, just use `grep -H` instead.

Answer (score 15):

Just add all files on the command line. You can use * or ? or whatever your shell allows as placeholder.

From manpage:

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
```

means: as many files as you wish.. or none if you want to grep stdin/pipe.

Answer (score 8):

```
grep 'mydata' *
```

The star `*` symbol signifies you want to search in multiple files. If you want to search through multiple files in multiple directories, you can add `-R` for a recursive search.

```
grep 'mydata' * -R
```

Comment: umm, I cant seem to use normal file patterns like `*.lua` here..?

Answer (score 3):

I ultimately did:

`grep -rli 'match_me' -- file1 file2 file3`

It appears to be widely standard on Debian/Bash systems that a double dash with no name means no more flags can be defined; Often implying that all remaining arguments are file paths. Though disclaimer, I do not know if this is the intended semantic or just a symptom that fits to the tools I use.